# How can I create a nav bar which stays fixed when scrolling in x-direction but scrolls away when scrolling down?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My main layout consists of a div for the navigation and a bigger div for the content of the page. Sometimes, when the content of the page gets too wide it is necessary to make the page scroll sideways. I want the navigation to stay fixed in that case. When scrolling down it should gradually scroll out of the picture.

I already tried:

- Listening to the scroll event and moving the navbar with transformX(...) (looks delayed and choppy sometimes and breaks layout of other elements inside my navigation bar)
- Making the navbar fixed and moving it in y direction instead when scrolling down (also looks choppy and breaks layout)
- Giving the content overflow-x: scroll (works fine in x-direction but navbar stays fixed in y-direction)
- Multiple other CSS shenanigans

My template looks like this:

```
<div #navbar class="navbar-fixed">
    <app-header fxLayout="column" class="displayheader"></app-header>
    <app-button-bar fxLayout="column"></app-button-bar>
</div>

<div id="mainsection" class="mainsection" fxLayout="row" fxFlex>
  <app-sidebar id="sidebar" fxLayout="column" fxFlex="300px"></app-sidebar>
  <div id="content" class="content" fxLayout="column" fxFlex>
</div>
```

Is there a solution that preferably works with plain css or javascript that is not performance intensive? I thought maybe the scroll overflow of the mainsection could just scroll over the navbar but I couldn't make it work.

Comment: `position:sticky;left:0;` inside a scrolling container should do :  https://jsfiddle.net/Lfnzjh7x/1/

Comment: Thank you so much, it works like a charm! I tried that originally but the position: sticky got ignored because I didn't specify a height on the parent container. With your example I could get it to work! Do you want to move this comment to an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you want to move this comment to an answer

Yes, if that helped you, it might help others too .

`Position : sticky;` should help you if your element stands inside a scrolling parent.

here is an exemple :

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

nav {
  position: sticky;
  left: 1em;
  /* I will stick to the left side of the screen while my scrolling parents remains in the view. 
  I will not overflow my scrolling parent and will stick inside it.
  I will be visible as long as my parent is and that no other sticky sibbling pushes me away*/
}

section {
  width: 110vw;
  aspect-ratio: 1;/*make it a big square, so scrollbar appear on div parent */
}

header,
nav,
section {
  margin: 1em;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <header>header</header>
  <nav> navbar </nav>
  <section>Section</section>
</div>
```